# How to get all contacts list?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm using .NET Maui.
I wrote this code to get all contacts list, but i get error
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Default' does not exist in the namespace 'Contacts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

:

```
 private async Task<List<Contact>> GetAllContactsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            //var contacts = await Contacts.GetAllAsync();
            var contacts = await Contacts.Default.GetAllAsync();
            return contacts.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions, such as the user denying permission to access the contacts.
            return new List<Contact>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the docs?  “Because of a namespace conflict, the Contacts type must be fully qualified when targeting iOS or macOS:”

Comment: While Jason's comment is patronizing. His response is accurate.

It's a tabbed footnote in the documentation located here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=macios

Answer (score 0):

you should refrence the asembley where Contact class is created.

I would suggest you create a dto folder or dto class library and create a class called contact.

Then.

using DTO;